# Let ${(a_n)}$ be a bounded sequence that does not converge.

Tags: analysis

Let ${(a_n)}$ be a bounded sequence that does not converge. Show that ${(a_n)}$ has two subsequences that converge to different limits.

- I think I am supposed to prove $(a_n)$ does not converge and for some reason all I can think of doing is to show it is not a monotone sequence but I do not know how, or maybe using the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem. I am completely confused any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that the limit exists iff $\liminf_n a_n=\limsup_n a_n$?

Comment: What space do you have at hand ? metric, vector (finite or infinite dimensional) ,topological ,..

Comment: @AlexR. no I am not, we have not covered that in class.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

1. Apply Bolzano-Weierstrass to get a subsequence that converges to a limit point $a$.
2. Because $(a_n)$ does not converge to $a$, show that there is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ which stays at a distance $> \varepsilon >0$ of $a$, for a certain $\varepsilon$.
3. Apply Bolzano-Weierstrass again to this new subsequence, and conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If it's bounded and does not converge, show that the $\limsup$ must be strictly greater than the $\liminf$.